# A message lost in space

Tags: support, status-completed, jobs

Today I opened the stackoverflow.com page, and I noticed that I received a message:
[image: message received]

But when I clicked on it, I got invalid page:
[image: invalid page]

I opened my messages, and the message is really not there.

So, what happened? Is it possible for people to somehow cancel or delete their messages?

---

**edit**:
I just checked my email account, and the message is there, with whole text, buttons, and everything. But here is still nowhere to be found.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have two users on Careers, both linked to the same SO account but we were picking the first, older account (which didn't have the message associated with it) as the one to show in the SO jobs tab.

I've merged the two accounts now and you will be able to see the message.